# How to create a multiple mysql replication

Tags: mysql-replication, mysql-cluster

My question is about to create a mysql replication server.

Here i have multiple slaves and i want replicate all respective database into multiple master server .

Que is that how could i set multiple master in a single server.

Answer (score 3):

Define your problem properly.

There are several options and constraints on how you design a MySQL cluster. What is it that you are trying to achieve? (availability, performance, offline backups, something else) What are your medium and long term objectives here? What is your budget? What is your hosting model?

> how could i set multiple master

Do you explicitly want to set up what is commonly referred to as multi-master replication? Do you really want to be able to apply writes anywhere in the cluster? Do you need realtime synchronization?

> in a single server

....is the exact opposite of a cluster. But you offer no explanation of what you mean here.

Even if you were to provide the answer to all of these questions, this is just the beginning of the analysis needed to choose the right architecture, never mind the details of the implementation.

You really need to do a lot more research yourself. Then, by all means, come back with more specific questions.

Comment: yes you are correct here , i am bit too low in my sql knowledge.

Comment: yes you are correct here , i am bit too low in my sql knowledge.

 I am expecting to get some idea from here so that i can able to understand it is possible or not.  Apart from this answer to your all queries    YES  i want to setup replications.   I have some clients having databses with same name and i want  to replicate their DB into my master server.



generally all slave DB are replicated to their respestive master

but i just want to know should i make all master into one machine

Comment: I think you need more help than a few answers here.

Answer (score 3):

So you're talking about several databases, that are already replicated between clients servers. And you need to add one more replication layer, and replicate them to your server, correct?

What's the purpose of this configuration? You can for example build your own datacenter with a couple of servers, and replicate this databases between your servers, just sharing them to the clients.

OR, you can create the backups of clients databases to your server using some backup solutions.